# Different behavior while getting the attributes of overridden properties?

Tags: c#, inheritance, custom-attributes

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var p = typeof(MyClass2).GetProperty("Value");
        var a = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), true);
        Console.WriteLine(a != null);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [CommandProperty()]
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    public override string Value { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
public class CommandPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
/* ... */
}

PropertyInfo prop = ***The PropertyInfo of MyClass2.Value***;
object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes( typeofCPA, true );
Attribute at =Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeofCPA, true);
if (attrs.Length == 0 && at != null)
{
    // Yes this happens.        
}
```

Why do I get no result from the first GetCustomAttributes call?

Comment: Having trouble following this example.  Where is the // No doesn't happens? And on which method is the `ObsoleteAttribute` defined?

Comment: So to be more clear, it appears that the problem is finding an attribute defined on an overridden member. I assume you want to return the attributes defined on that member anywhere within the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) (inherited to PropertyInfo) states;

> This method ignores the inherit parameter for properties and events.
>   To search the inheritance chain for attributes on properties and
>   events, use the appropriate overloads of the
>   Attribute.GetCustomAttributes method.

In other words, (wrong) behavior by design.

Comment: In addition I found this:
inherit 
- Type: System.Boolean 
- true to search this member's inheritance chain to find the attributes; otherwise, false. **This parameter is ignored for properties and events; see Remarks.** - Thanks